# Storing Kerberos session keys

Tags: kerberos

How do you store Kerberos service keys in a Java program.

I have created a client and serverside program, where the serverside sites on my server and client is used on my computer, i can get to the serivce and use it - i then close it.

I want to reach the service again without having to log back into Kerberos, how could i do this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

As a client? If you, oyu need a credential cache. This is done by logging in into the OS and have the cache maintained by your OS. Java accesses this cache.